# Change Size of Tick Labels D3

Tags: svg, d3.js, label, legend

I want to increase the size of the numbers which label my legend using D3.  The legend is made as follows:

```
map.legend_axes = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(map.legend_scales)
            .orient('bottom')
            .tickSize(map.settings.legend.ticks);
```

Is there an argument I can pass which will increase the size of the numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a CSS class that increases the font size and then add that class to the text on the axis:

```
d3.selectAll("axisElement")
  .classed("large-font", true);
```